Cast variable to right type automatically in Python
Is there a way in Python to implement type-casting that automatically chooses the right type?
Say you have a class:
class Foo:
    foo: list[int]

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = cast(list[int], api.get())

You know that api.get() always returns list[int] but it's a weird library with haphazard type hints, so it claims that it's (say) FunkyContainerType when it's not. Also you can't be bothered to create a correct stub file for the library today because deadlines.
self.foo = cast(list[int], api.get()) creates a lot visual noise in the code, which is also redundant if the type of self.foo is already defined. Moreover, if the variable has a custom type, you have to import the type at runtime for the program not to crash, so you can't put it in a stub file and you'll run into issues with circular imports more often.
I'd much rather use self.foo = cast(api.get()) that finds out what type self.foo is and casts the result of the API call to that type.
So the key desiderata are (1) don't state the type redundantly, (2) change nothing about the runtime behavior, i.e. no type imports at runtime, and (3) minimal visual clutter.
Notes: (1) This question is about exactly what it says it is. It is not about copying or converting values at runtime. It is about type hints. (2) The use of cast is to supply extra information to the type-checker that you know but that the type-checker cannot infer.

You are aware that typing.cast doesn't actually transform any values at all? It's just additional typing annotation. Is this what you want?

What is wrong with just self.foo = api.get()? Perhaps self.foo: list[int] = api.get()? Annotate api.get to return -> list[int]…?

" that finds out what type self.foo is and casts the result of the API call to that type." this doesn't make any sense. What do you think cast is doing here? cast is only useful to tell the type checker "this is actually not the type you think it is, it is some other type, that I, a human, will tell you to assume it is"

@deceze Yes to your first question. Let's assume that I can't modify get() because it's third-party code and might (in general) return anything. But I know that it'll return list[int]. I.e. it actually is the sort of situation where you want to either cast or use type assertions.

@juanpa.arrivillaga I think cast does exactly what you say it does. In fact I'm only interested in the type-checking behavior. I explicitly want to avoid any complications at runtime (I mention problems with circular imports and wanting to use stub files).

"I'd much rather use self.foo = cast(api.get()) that finds out what type self.foo is and casts the result of the API call to that type.": And how exactly is the type checker going to find out the "real" type without correct type hints and without running the code? You are essentially asking it to do a runtime task at type-checking time.

@InSync The purpose of the cast function is to tell the type-checker something that you know about the data but the type-checker cannot infer. In this case I know that the data is list[int] but the type-checker doesn't. (I've written plenty of type stubs for insufficiently typed third-party libraries. That's definitely another option. But that's not what I had any questions about today.)

# type: ignore or better (for Pyright) # pyright: ignore [reportAssignmentType] do the trick.
The assignment doesn't change or extend the type of the attribute. (H/t juanpa.arrivillaga.)
What also works is:
self.foo = cast(Any, api.get())
It does not change the type of self.foo to list[int] | Any as I would've expected but has my desired result (of not changing the type). But I like it less now because it's less obvious to me and adds more clutter in my opinion.

Any basically signals "stop caring about types here", which obviates the point of type hinting.

I think you just need # type: ignore

The type of self.foo is type(self.foo). The only way to change its type to list is list(self.foo). But you're talking about type hints here. Type hints are only hints, they do not modify the actual values.

@deceze I thought so too, but try it out. It works for me with Pyright.

@Jeyekomon I'm talking about type hints only. The value is of type list[int]; the typechecker just doesn't know it. I do not want to copy the list or add any other runtime shenanigans.

@juanpa.arrivillaga # type: ignore works too! I prefer # pyright: ignore [reportAssignmentType].

Define "works for me". It'll "work" insofar as it won't raise any complaints, because you're explicitly turning type checking off there…?!

@deceze By “works for me” I mean that I want Pyright to know that self.foo is of type list[int] and not Unknown, Any, list[int] | Unknown, list[int] | Any or some other variation. Any (and Unknown depending on strictness settings) wouldn't raise complaints either, but I want the type-checking. (cast is for situations when you know something about the data that Pyright doesn't, and you want to tell it. I know that self.foo is list[int] and not Any or Unknown.)

@DawnDrescher the only thing I would point out is that # type: ignore shouold work with any type checker, is it possible to use both?

@juanpa.arrivillaga Sadly not really, but a given project will have a config somewhere that specifies which type-checker is used by the maintainers of the project. I'm using Pyright, so with just the Pyright comment, I'll still see all other unrelated type errors in that line. With both comments (if that's even syntactically possible), the more general one would screen off that effect and I wouldn't see unrelated type errors because Pyright also respects # type: ignore. Maybe MyPy has some analogous comment syntax?

cast is a general tool which mypy and the like are hard-coded to recognize. In a special case, you can define your own cast-like function that is restricted to a specific return type (and thus doesn't required special handling by the type checker).
def as_list_int(x: Any) -> list[int]:
    return x


class Foo:
    foo: list[int]

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = as_list_int(api.get())

The real problem here is that api.get should be hinted as returning a list[int]. If that's not possible (because it really can return values that aren't list[int]), then you probably need another function anyway to verify that this call returns a list[int] (raising an exception if it does not) or creates a list[int] from whatever it does return.

Thanks! That solution works! I like that it uses types only in places where they are ignored at runtime (don't need to be imported at runtime). But it still states the list[int] type redundantly. That also means that you'd need a separate function for each such type. I still prefer the # pyright: ignore [reportAssignmentType] solution. (It strikes me as more readable and less surprising than my original cast(Any, ...) idea.)

It's only redundant if you want type inference, which isn't really what tools like mypy are designed to do. If you consider api.get to be polymorphic in its return value (that is, truly capable of returning a value of whatever type you request), then type inference fits with type checking. However, that's not how api.get works. It really does return a value of a specific type, but the return type doesn't reflect that.
